# Git - find a possible branch on which another branch has been based on

Tags: git, version-control, merge

We have a following GIT "working habit". I will shortly describe it to clarify the context of my later question.

We work with three permanent branches (**DEV**,**STAGE**,**MASTER**).
In general **STAGE** should be in sync with **MASTER**. But **DEV** is allways considered as "dirty" which means it can contain lot of commits which never get merged into **STAGE** or **MASTER**. We only merge feature branches or single commits from **DEV** into **STAGE**. Then we merge **STAGE** into **MASTER**.

Now at some point we started a huge "change set" (major project upgrade) and created a dedicated feature branch, say **UPGRADE** for this.
The work on this feature was going on for 3 months.

Now I would like to merge that huge feature branch into **STAGE** but I am not 100% sure if I created the branch **UPGRADE** from **STAGE/MASTER** or from **DEV**.
We did not document this.

Since **DEV** is "dirty" I can not do the merge if **UPGRADE** was branched from **DEV**!

So here is my problem: Now I would like to be sure that we branched **UPGRADE** from **STAGE/MASTER** and not from **DEV** (I should have taken STAGE/MASTER but I am not sure now). How can I fetch the most reliable informations from the repositry?

I did already some research and tried to use "**git merge-base**".
Here are the three commands I tried.

1) `git show --summary 'git merge-base upgrade dev'`

2) `git show --summary 'git merge-base upgrade stage'`

3) `git show --summary 'git merge-base upgrade master'`

But they all deliver the same treeish which is only a few days old.

So here my question again: Now I would like to be sure that we branched **UPGRADE** from **STAGE/MASTER** and not from **DEV**. How can I fetch the most reliable informations from the repositry?

Comment: This, in general, is why [long-lived feature branches is an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187520/54997).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to use any of the below command:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
gitk --all
```

You can view the branch structure apparently. Such as there has `master` and `new` branch in below graph, and we can find `new` branch is created from `master` branch. You can use the same way to find where **`UPDATE`** was created from.

```
* 0d04f17 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) 5
* 74d5ed3 5
* 6146194 4
* e5ddeac 3
* a33f9ee 2
* 8373f5d hi1
* 3df7047 hi
* 3f27319 6
| * f0cca03 (new) 1
|/
* 38236ae Update config
```

---

#### Rebase `UPDATE` branch to a past commit

Assume `UPDATE` branch is created from `DEV` branch, the past commit is commit `D` and the commit history looks like:

```
A---B---C---D---E     master
     \
      F---G---H---I   DEV
           \
            J---K---L UPDATE
```

**1.Rebase `UPDATE` directly (don’t keep the original `UPDATE` branch):**

```
git  rebase --onto <commit id for D> DEV UPDATE
```

Then the commit history will like:

```
              J'---K'---L' UPDATE
             /
A---B---C---D---E          master
     \
      F---G---H---I        DEV
```

**2.Rebase changes of `UPDATE` to a new branch and keep the original `UPDATE` branch:**

```
git checkout -b new <commit id for D>
git rebase --onto new DEV <commit id for L>
git branch -f new
git checkout new
```

Then the commit history will like:

```
              J'---K'---L' new
             /
A---B---C---D---E          master
     \
      F---G---H---I        DEV
           \
            J---K---L      UPDATE
```

Comment: OK, it looks like we branched from DEV after analysing the tree. I wasn't 100% convinced because the three is lot more complex than the example above. So I doublechecked by manually searching for one older example-commit which is only present in DEV and UPGRADE. I found one and this is a better prove for me.

So now, is there a way to "rebase" the "UPGRADE" branch? means create a new branch from a past commit and apply all changesets in branch "UPGRADE" to it?

Comment: Yes you can.  1. git checkout <hash-of-commit> 2. git checkout -b new_branch 3. git checkout UPGRADE 4. git rebase new_branch

Comment: @ArturCichosz No matter how the commit history complicated, you just need to find the cross point for `UPDATE` and the other branch. And you can rebase `UPDATE` branch by these two ways which I added in my answer.

Comment: Thx. Marina, option 1 worked perfectly.  I did not try option 2, but why <commit id for L>?

Comment: If you use `<commit id for L>`, git will rebase the commits from `J` to `L` into a detached HEAD. If you use `UPDATE` instead of `L`, git will rebase the branch of `UPDATE`.